# Update SQLite error

Tags: android

To update a value in my SQLite database (android) I use following method. The table is calles objects, the field I want to update is showinfo1, of a specific item with a certain id and level.

```
public void insertString(int id, int level, String field, String value){

        myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE OBJECTS SET " + field + "=" + value + " WHERE _ID=" + id + " AND LEVEL =" + level);

    }
```

I have an error which I think is strange. It says there is 'nosuchcolumn' while there actually is one..:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: true: UPDATE OBJECTS set showinfo1=true WHERE _ID=6 AND LEVEL =1
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe my query is wrong?

Comment: your query is wrong indeed. you need to put your value between single quotes. yet, this is not the proper way of doing it. use the update method in the database object, rather than the execSQL. it'll handle formatting and escaping your input

Comment: I see if I can do it that way.. To get items right now, I use rawQuery(SELECT * FROM...) and then a cursor.. is this also not to proper solution to get items?

Comment: no, there is a query method that takes all kind of parameter. It results in queries easier to maintain and debug, as project, query, and parameters are separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query should be like this

```
public void insertString(int id, int level, String field, String value){

    myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE OBJECTS SET " + field + "='" + value + "' WHERE _ID=" + id + " AND LEVEL =" + level);

}
```

your string is translating to `UPDATE OBJECTS SET URFIELD = true ...` and it is searching for the column named `true`, so it should be `URFIELD = 'true'` (same goes for `ID` and `LEVEL` if they were `text`)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite did not have a separate Boolean storage type. Instead, Boolean values should be stored as integers 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Comment: I don't compare to a boolean, I just compare two strings which happen to be able to be true or false...

Comment: but then you can use integer for storing. It has a couple of benefits. you need less memory.